# SELECT IDENTITY not grabbing the most recent ID created

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

In another question, I had asked how to configure my `ExecuteScalar` and use `SCOPE_INDENTITY` to grab my newly created PK `PersonID`.  The first set of insert statements that enter a person into the table are working, and the `PersonID` is at #39 from newly created records.  When I set a breakpoint on the AddNewCustomer method and work my way through the code, `newPersonID` is set to "1" and stays there the whole time.  Does anyone have any idea of why it's not showing "39, or 40" for my newly created records for `newPersonID`.

```
protected void AddNewCustomer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string nFirstName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFirstName")).Text;
string nLastName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtLastName")).Text;
string nEmergency = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmergency")).Text;
string nCell = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCell")).Text;
string nAge = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAge")).Text;
string nActivityCard = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtActivityCard")).Text;
string nInitials = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInitials")).Text;
string nBoat = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtBoat")).Text;
string nGroup = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtGroup")).Text;


    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, LastName, Emergency#, Cell#, Age, ActivityCard, CraftType, Initials, Group#) " +
    "values(@FirstName, @LastName, @Emergency, @Cell, @Age, @ActivityCard, @Boat, @Initials, @Group); " +
    "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();");

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nFirstName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nLastName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emergency", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nEmergency;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cell", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nCell;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nAge;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActivityCard", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nActivityCard;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Initials", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nInitials;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Boat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nBoat;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Group", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nGroup;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", ddlTripTime.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", ddlTripType.SelectedItem.ToString());


    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    int newPersonID = System.Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    con.Close();

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd1.CommandText ="insert into TripSchedule(TripType, PersonID, Time, Date) values (@Type, @newPerson, @Time, @Date);" +
    "SELECT Person.PersonID, Person.FirstName AS FirstName, Person.LastName AS LastName, Person.Emergency# AS Emergency#, Person.Cell# AS Cell#, Person.Age AS Age, " +
    "Person.ActivityCard AS ActivityCard, Person.CraftType AS CraftType, Person.Initials AS Initials, Person.Group# AS Group# " +
    "FROM Person INNER JOIN " +
    "TripSchedule ON Person.PersonID = TripSchedule.PersonID where TripSchedule.Date = @Date and " +
    "TripSchedule.Time = @Time and TripSchedule.TripType = @Type;";

    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", ddlTripTime.SelectedItem);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", ddlTripType.SelectedItem);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newPerson", newPersonID);
    GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

}

**EDIT** Per OP's comment on another answer, here is the actual Error Message:

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the 
name 'FirstName'.
```

It's my first ItemTemplate of my gridview. I get this error message when I enter new data into the textboxes of my gridview, then hit my submit button which is linked to my `AddNewCustomer` method

Comment: What is the purpose of the first SELECT? You don't use the results of that query. Try to remove and look at what value is returned now by the ExecuteScalar

Comment: @Steve I added the first select statement because otherwise I was getting a gridview error saying the dataview had no rows under my EVAL statements on the ASP page

Comment: yes, but that's a *different* problem.

Comment: I cleaned it up and added the actual error message he posted to another answer.  Hopefully I got it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query includes 2 selects

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Person.PersonID, 
...
"SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();");
```

So when you execute

```
int newPersonID = System.Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

You always get Person.PersonID which is 1.

UPDATE:

1)

You get 
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the 
name 'FirstName'. because you bind a data at

```
GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
GridView1.DataBind();
```

So if you need to bind any data, then your SELECT which you removed, should be at the end of your query. Example:

```
INSERT ...;
INSERT ...;
SELECT ...
```

This will be more logical, because you insert data and then select some result to show on a page.

2) You could "combine" 2 INSERT-queries into 1 call. You simply need to do

```
INSERT ...;
INSERT ... VALUES(..., SCOPE_IDENTITY());
SELECT ...
```

Namely:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, LastName, Emergency#, Cell#, Age, ActivityCard, CraftType, Initials, Group#) " +
    "values(@FirstName, @LastName, @Emergency, @Cell, @Age, @ActivityCard, @Boat, @Initials, @Group);"
+ "insert into TripSchedule(TripType, PersonID, Time, Date) values (@Type, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @Time, @Date);" +
    "SELECT Person.PersonID, Person.FirstName AS FirstName, Person.LastName AS LastName, Person.Emergency# AS Emergency#, Person.Cell# AS Cell#, Person.Age AS Age, " +
    "Person.ActivityCard AS ActivityCard, Person.CraftType AS CraftType, Person.Initials AS Initials, Person.Group# AS Group# " +
    "FROM Person INNER JOIN " +
    "TripSchedule ON Person.PersonID = TripSchedule.PersonID where TripSchedule.Date = @Date and " +
    "TripSchedule.Time = @Time and TripSchedule.TripType = @Type;";
```

Bottom Line:

Move all sql code into a stored procedure.

Comment: Like I said in the comment above, if I don't have that first select statement, I get an error when I try to add a new user in my gridview because it says on my EVAL statements in ASP.NET, that the row has no data.  How could I get around that?

Comment: This simply makes no sense because you select some data and do not use them anywhere. Just get rid of first SELECT and share error message if you get any.

Comment: Okay, I just removed the first select statement and ran the application and it said this: `DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'FirstName'.`  It's my first  ItemTemplate of my gridview.  I get this error message when I enter new data into the textboxes of my gridview, then hit my submit button which is linked to my AddNewCustomer method

Comment: @user3267755, any alterations to the question should occur in the *question*, not in a response to another answer.  This underlying error is what needs to be fixed.